# SharePoint 2013: EVERY App (list/library) shows 'ReferenceError: 'Strings' is undefined' -- can't view anything

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

When going to 'Site Contents', any app (list/lib) that I click, the default page shows a wall of 'ReferenceError: 'Strings' is undefined'. This is in IE 11. This doesn't happen in Chrome. In addition, certain LVWPs aren't affected on Site Pages. I'm very confused, and I can't view anything in my app currently. Any assistant would be incredibly helpful. I think this is so strange because only OOB components seem to be affected by this. Screenshots below

What I've done so far:

- enabled DOM storage in IE Internet Options
- put my domain in compatibility view

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]
This was a TrendMicro error, and it's fixed now. 
December 6, 2016: Trend Micro received several customer reports of a false alarm (FA) detection on what is believed to be a file related to Microsoft SharePoint: “initstrings.js” with the detection name of JS_NEMUCOD.SMAA15 using the Official Pattern Release (OPR) of 12.941.00.

As of 15:15 GMT, Trend Micro has removed OPR 12.941.00 from our global ActiveUpdate (AU) servers and is in the process of uploading a rollback version of the last known good pattern file (12.943.00).
The Global Smart Scan version of 12.943.00 is available now (as of approximately 15:40 GMT) and the conventional version of the pattern is estimated to be available by 17:00 GMT.